# API or datasets for websites demographics (age & gender distributions)

Tags: data-request, api, demographics, global

### Data request

**Data:** I am looking for an API or dataset where I can find age distribution (age groups: percentage of an age group according to the population) and gender distributions **for the biggest websites of each country** like: Facebook (USA, Germany, France aso), Twitter (USA, Germany, France aso), Spiegel Online, Instagram aso. Something like [Alexa Top 500 sites](http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/DE) but with statistics about their audience.

**Context:** I am working on my Master's Thesis and would like to compare my scientific samples to the population.

**Region:** I need Data from the whole world.

**License:** Unfortunately I am a Student and can't spend more that 50 Euro on this data.

**Format:** A JSON API would be perfect. XML, CSV, XLSX or any other common data type is ok too.

**Authority:** I need the data to be reliable. That means, the sources of the data have to be visible and official.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. It's completely different data required.

Comment: how is this completely different

Comment: OP is asking about website user demographics in this question, and the other one is just country demographics